# How to filter the results of Type.GetMethods with a specific signature?

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to filter methods with a specific signature defined in my class. See the code below,

```
 public class A {
    delegate float op(int from, int to);
    List<op> operations;
    public A () {
        MethodInfo[] methods = this.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        // filter goes here.
        // foreach method which is op
        // operations.Add(m)
    }
    private float operation1(int from, int to) {
        return 1;
    }

    private float operation2(int from, int to) {
        return 2;
    }


    public int other2() {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

How to do this?

```
MethodInfo[] methods = this.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        foreach (MethodInfo m in methods)
        {
            try
            {
                op operation = (op)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(op), this, m);
                operations.Add(operation);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // nothing except logging
            }
        }
```

Comment: Googling (and Bing-ing) "MethodInfo get parameters" returns this as a first result: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters(v=vs.110).aspx  What search terms did you try?

Comment: @PeteBaughman So I should check the parameter list and return type. Can I get a delegate to the method and add it to my list so I can call it by m(), or I can only use the MethodInfo.Invoke to call it in runtime?

Comment: Search the MethodInfo docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo(v=vs.110).aspx page for "Delegate".  You'll find two methods that do what you want - CreateDelegate(Type) and CreateDelegate(Type, object)

Comment: @PeteBaughman Tried "GetMethods filter signature". Anyway, I got this done, instead to check the parameter list and return type. I catch all exception and ignore it. The code is updated, would you please have a look at it and the only concern is performance. This code is gonna compiled to xcode project and finally run in IOS. I am not sure if it is a dirty way to do this. Thx sir!